# Ariel will not send through our SMTP server

Tags: smtp

I'm currently working at a university that uses Ariel software to send ILL documents to teachers at other universities.  They do this by e-mail the documents to the users.  We recently switched from our own mail servers to google servers.

The problem started right after the switch.  The mail info has been properly put in for both the new google system (which locks up the software) and the still in use unauthenticated smtp server.  Ariel refuses to use either one so hopefully someone on here knows of something I can do to get this going because the software support from the company is poor at best because most schools are going over to Illiad.

Any help much appreciated.